# Does any sum of twin primes, where the sum is greater than 12, also represents the sum of 2 other distinct primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

I was in the midst of proving a conjecture when I came across an observation that led me to forming a potentially new conjecture. The conjecture goes as follows:

> Any given sum of twin primes (specifically the two primes in a twin prime pair, ie. $11$ and $13$) where the sum is greater than $12$, also represents the sum of 2 other distinct primes.

I've proven this for the first $1000$ twin primes and my computer is calculating beyond that set. Anyways, does anybody have any ideas of how I could go about proving this conjecture? I apologize if this conjecture has already been posed.

Comment: [This OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A045917) lists how many ways even integers can be written as sums of primes - and it suggests *every* even integer greater than $12$ is the sum of at least two distinct pairs of primes, which would imply your conjecture. Of course, we have no idea how to prove Goldbach's conjecture, and I would assume that your conjecture is not much easier.

Comment: Interesting, I noticed by hand calculation that it looked as if it applied to other numbers but I was hesitant to pose such as topic without examining it further. Thanks for the link!

Comment: It's easy to come up with conjectures about prime numbers. But aye, proving them, that's the tough part.

Comment: See my blog http://ideasfornumbertheory.wordpress.com for some possible insights.

Comment: Also a special case of [this mathSE conjecture](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860437/is-this-a-known-conjecture-given-odd-primes-p-q-with-p-q-sufficiently-lar).

Answer (score 2):

There is a conjecture which states that the total number of writing $n$ as a sum of two odd primes is $\sim \frac{n}{2(\ln n)^2}$.
 This shows that the sum of two twin primes will be a sum of two other primes as well.
So, your conjecture is a special case of an older conjecture.
(But ,I always liked elementary conjectures too,so do not be disappointed if your observation is "already stated" this has happened to me many times.)