# Is this a known conjecture? Given odd primes $p,q$ with $p + q$ sufficiently large, must there exist a different pair $p',q'$ with $p+q = p'+q'$?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

Conjecture:

> There is a natural number $N\in\mathbb N$ such that given odd primes $p,q$ with $p+q>N$
>   there are primes $p',q'$ where $p' \notin \{p,q\}$ such that $p+q=p'+q'$.

Is this known?

Comment: Any parity constraint?  If you look at large odd numbers of the form $2+q$, that decomposition is unique.  Or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restricted to odd primes, the conjecture is that the number of [Goldbach partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) is 0 or at least 2, with finitely many exceptions.  The Goldbach conjecture is  that this number is never 0.

See also [Goldbach's comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_comet).

---

Not restricted to odd primes, as lulu points out in the comments, the conjecture is false.